# Error 2 Use of unassigned local variable 'Y'

Tags: c#, .net, variables, local-variables, unassigned-variable

Again i run into an error i don't mean to bug anyone but I'm getting an error on this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Input_Program
{
    class Program
    {
       private static void Main()
        {

           char Y;
            char N;

           Console.WriteLine("Welcome to my bool program!");
           Console.WriteLine("Input a NON capital y or n when told to.");




            if(Y == 'y')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Thank you,Please wait.....");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for you answers!

Comment: Umm... Y is never assigned a value?

Comment: The general rule is that you should always *initialize* a variable when you declare it. So you shouldn't write `char Y;`, but instead write `char Y = 'y';`.

Comment: Oh i fetch input with c# I'm used to c++ syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `char Y` is not initialized before using. Try to give a default value when declaring.

**EDIT** It seems that you want the users to input something, and assign it to the variable Y. Try:

```
Y = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
```

Comment: But if it has a value then i can't do the if else's

Comment: `Console.ReadKey()` allows users input something, and assign it to the variable `y`, you can use `if-else` to do something according to the value of `y`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(Y == 'y')
```

`Y` is a local variable which isn't assigned anything. So, you assign it any value before the `if` statement to make any comparison.

```
Y = 'a';  // or some character
```

Comment: If `Y` is assigned `a`, then `Y=='y'` yields to **false** and so the statements in `if` won't execute.

Answer (score 1):

You're not setting Y to anything, and you're also not reading anything from the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

You could explicitly set it to null.

```
char Y = '<whatever_is_the_default_char>';
```

That would get rid of the compiler error.

The  root cause of the compiler error is that when it goes to compile the if conditional nothing as been assigned to Y. The above is considered an assignment.